# Python. Check if index exists in a list of possible dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have this:

```
list_name = [0, 1, 2, 3]
list_name[0] = {}
list_name[0]['test'] = 'any value'
```

I want to know if a key of the list exists or not. Usually I use:

```
if 3 not in list_name:
    print("this doesn't exist")
else:
    print("exists")
```

And testing this for example for number 3 is working. It says "exists". If I check for number 999 is working, it says "this doesn't exist".

The problem is that it is not working for 0. As you can see, 0 value in the list has a dictionary. And I need to check if 0 exists or not in the list (doesn't matter if it has a dictionary or not). How to achieve this? Using python3, thank you.

Comment: [] - this is a list, it  has no keys, only indexes and values

{} - this is a dictionary, it has keys and values
[dicts, lists, tuples...](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/python/data_structures.html)

Comment: `3 not in list_name` is not checking for index 3, its checking if the value `3` is not in `list_name`. Its equivalent to a "contains" method. Your list looks like: `[{'test': 'any value'}, 1, 2, 3]`, and that doesn't contain a 0; though it does have something at the 0th index. You can use `len(my_list)` to check for length.

Comment: Thanks @EugeneK, corrected array => dictionary

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis my whole point was - maybe you misunderstand how list and dictionary work. Because your list does not have 0 value. Please read an article from my first comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `try` `except` for check index is exists or not

```
try:
    if list_name[6]:
        print("exists")

except IndexError:
    print("this doesn't exist")
```

Output

> this doesn't exist

Answer (score 5):

If element `0` exists in the list, then the length of the list *must* be greater than zero. So you could use:

```
if len(list_name) > 0:
    print("0 exists")
else:
    print("0 does not exist")
```

As a side note, `{}` is a dictionary, not an array.